# Versionar Base de Datos en desarrollo similar a versión de código fuente en GitLab o similares

Tags: mysql, git

Desarrollo con NetBeans mis aplicaciones JavaSwing. Cada tanto voy versionando con GIT local y luego a GITLAB en remoto como seguridad. Esto me funciona bien.

La consulta es ¿cómo puedo ir versionando la base de datos que estoy desarrollando con el sistema?

Desarrollar la base de datos me refiero a crear nuevas tablas, modificar y/o agregar campos a medida que la aplicación avance.

Comment: Hola @Paraguayo33. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Está claro que querés ir versionando la estructura de la base de datos, pero ¿a qué te estás refiriendo con "*modificar campos*"? ¿En qué se diferenciaría de guardar la estructura de la base junto a cada versión?

Comment: Y a medida que vamos desarrollando, podríamos agregar un nuevo campo alguna tabla o modificar el valor por defecto del campo. Agregar una nueva relación o control de integridad etc.

Answer (score 2):

La idea seria tener un archivo `sql` con la estructura de las tablas y relaciones y cada que sea modificado darle un commit a ese cambio. Por ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIO ( 
username VARCHAR(13),
activo BIT,
nombre VARCHAR(180),    
rol INTEGER UNSIGNED,
oficina VARCHAR(8),
mail VARCHAR(100),
telefono VARCHAR(30),
celular VARCHAR(35)
);
```

Y agregamos nuestro campo

```
CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIO ( 
username VARCHAR(13),
activo BIT,
nombre VARCHAR(180),    
rol INTEGER UNSIGNED,
oficina VARCHAR(8),
mail VARCHAR(100),
telefono VARCHAR(30),
extension VARCHAR(6), -- <--- nuevo campo
celular VARCHAR(35),
);
```

Teniendo en nuestro diff

[image: Diff de ejemplo]

---

Un software que promete estar orientado a sql es gitsql, aunque no lo he probado mucho.

Comment: Claro, este sería un método manual. Como última opción sirve. Me preguntaba si hay algun Soft, preferentemente open para ir creando y versionando. Igual muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: @Paraguayo33 hice un edit

Answer (score 0):

Las bases de datos forman parte de nuestra infraestructura y para versionar infraestructura existen muchas soluciones en el mercado. Algunas de ellas son:

- [Puppet](https://puppet.com/product/how-puppet-works)
- [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)
- [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/)

El concepto básico es que si quieres versionar algo entonces debes poder crearlo de forma automática, si no es así el versionamiento ha sido inútil.

Lo ideal sería que puedas versionar toda tu infraestructura, y hablando de bases de datos podrías versionar desde la creación del servidor y la instalación de la base de datos hasta la creación y modificación de tablas y demás propiedades de dicha base de datos.

Desde el momento en el que te preguntas este tipo de cosas has entrado al siguiente nivel y te aconsejo seguir investigando sobre el tema.